# Update a field of an object in a list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a prop that is a list of objects. My reducer is meant to update a certain field of the object and append it to the list, the value to update is provided via action.payload (**which is another prop of the store**).

I know that for simply adding the object in the list I can use the spread operator like this

```
function myReducer(state=[],action){
    case something:
        return [...state,action.payload];
    case default:
        return state;
}
```

but say I have a change `action.payload.aCertainField` and then append this to the list of objects. When I did something like this:

```
action.payload.aCertainField = aCertainValue;
return [...state,action.payload];
```

But it actually changed the other prop's `aCertainField` as well. I do not want that. Is there a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as following, using ES6:

```
let { aCertainField, id } = action.payload.obj;

//find the index of object in that array hoping the id is unique for the object
let indexOfObject = state.findIndex( (item) => item.id === id );

let actualObject = Object.assign({}, state[indexOfObject], { aCertainField });

return [
  ...state.slice(0, indexOfObject),
  actualObject,
  ...state.slice(indexOfObject+1)
]
```

NOTE: Thinks that id is the unique key for the object structure and aCertainField is the value to update